# Different error reports for apparently same problems

Tags: haskell

Playing with Haskell's typeclasses I created an instance of a typeclass of a list, whose elements are not an instance of that typeclass:

```
class Three a where
    three :: a -> [a]

instance (Three a) => Three [a] where
    three x = [x, x, x]
```

I get a different error message for a list of Integers and for a list of Chars:

**Chars**

```
*Main> three ['c']

<interactive>:11:1:
    No instance for (Three Char)
      arising from a use of `three'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Three Char)
    In the expression: three ['c']
    In an equation for `it': it = three ['c']
```

**Integers**

*Main> three [1, 2]

```
<interactive>:12:8:
    Ambiguous type variable `t0' in the constraints:
      (Num t0) arising from the literal `1' at <interactive>:12:8
      (Three t0) arising from a use of `three' at <interactive>:12:1-5
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: 1
    In the first argument of `three', namely `[1, 2]'
    In the expression: three [1, 2]
```

Why??

(Now, the error for Chars is understood - there is no instance for it. But the ambiguity error for Integers is not clear to me. I thought that maybe that't because integers are already an instance of something (Num) so I created another arbitrary typeclass and an instance of it for Char, but got the same error for Char as before).

I'll appreciate your help

Comment: Integer literals are overloaded, their type is `(Num a) => a`. Character literals are of type `Char`, hence different errors. Try `three [1::Int]`.

Comment: Just copy that to an answer that the OP can accept it...

Comment: @n.m. - thanks for the explanation. There one thing I still don't understand, which is why is there ambiguity? So what if integer types are overloaded, can't they be overloaded by a few typeclasses? I mean, `three` works only on typeclass `Three`, and if an integer literal doesn't have an instance for `Three` then I would expect to get an error saying so...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Types are not overloaded, functions are. What error message would you like to see? "No instance for <what>"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error points out that there is no instance for `Three` for `Char`. As you say, easy!

However, in the second case, since the type of your numeric literals is unknown/polymorphic, GHC can't tell if there *is* an instance for them or not. Hence, the error isn't about a missing instance, but an ambiguous variable.

You could, for example, have valid instances for `Three` for both `Int` and `Double`. How would GHC know which to pick?

(ignoring extended defaulting, that is).

So the error is different, because the type of error actually *is* different.